# Linux Mint clock is sometimes wrong, sometimes fine

Tags: time, clock

I'm running linux mint on an asus laptop.

Throughout multiple installs of linux (always mint, but different environments), the clock is always wrong sometimes.

It's not off by an even multiple of an hour of half-hour, it can be off by seemingly random times.

I remember having a service on an old install along the lines of datectl, however in order to actually fix the problem, the service would have to be restarted.

I haven't seen it change on me, so I can assume that it's only when coming out of sleep/booting.

Is this a bad CMOS clock battery? I would have thought that a service would be able to compensate for this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i recommend you to install `ntp` service with `apt-get install ntp`.

To sync the hardware clock with the system clock you can use `hwclock` command with option `--systohc` or `-w`

```
hwclock -w
```

this will set the hardware clock to the current system time

Comment: As of 11/22, This no longer works on Linux Mint 21, kernel 5.15.0-52-generic